# what is relation between content-length and byte ranges in HTTP/1.1?

Tags: http, byte, content-length

I am not grasping the idea behind content-length and byte ranges as specified by HTTP 1.1
Is there are connection between the two of some sort? If a client requests in terms of byte ranges, say 0-100 out of 200, will the first response contain the "content-length" equal to 100 bytes followed by 100 actual data?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body […] sent to the recipient […]

In a non-multipart message the entity-body is the body of the HTTP message as it only contains one entity. So the *Content-Length* value indicates the length of the message body that is sent and not the size of the whole resource.

So for a partial content response on a 0-100 [byte range request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1) (first byte and last byte inclusive) the *Content-Length* of the response will be 0 ≤ *size* ≤ 101.

In case of a 12345 byte long resource the response could look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 0-100/12345
Content-Length: 101

… 101 bytes of content …
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. Was pretty confusing, the HTTP response you wrote cleared it out nicely!

Comment: helped me solve my issue. android mediaplayer was giving an incorrect duration thanks a bunch.